# assign a matched group values into the variable in php

Tags: php

Using php how to split the usernames,passwords,datadasename,hostname,etc into a variable.

For Example:

> $db =
>   "databasename://username:password@hostname/dbname"
>
> $
>   databasename = databasename
>
> $user = username
>
> $pass = password
>
> $host = hostname
>
> $dbname = dbname

I have tried with grouping in regular expression. but I don't know how to assign the group values into the variable.

> preg_match("(^([a-z]*?)://([a-z]*?):([a-z]*?)@[a-z]*?)/([a-z]*?)$)", $db , $matches);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
$db = "databasename://username:password@hostname/dbname";
if (preg_match("~^([a-z]+)://([a-z]+):([a-z]+)@[a-z]+/([a-z]+)\$~i",
        $db , $matches))
   list($ignore, $databasename, $username, $password, $dbname) = $matches;

var_dump($databasename);
var_dump($username);
var_dump($password);
var_dump($dbname);
```

which gives:

```
string(12) "databasename"
string(8) "username"
string(8) "password"
string(6) "dbname"
```

Or you can use named groups.

Comment: my input may be this 
$db = "databasename://username:password@hostname/dbname"; [or] this
$db = "databasename://username:password@192.168.8.20/dbname";

for that I have wrote the regular expression like this.
 if (preg_match("~^([a-zA-Z]+)://([a-zA-Z]+):([a-zA-Z]+)@([a-z]|([0-9]{1,3}[.][0-9]{1,3}[.][0-9]{1,3}[.][0-9]{1,3}))+/([a-z]+)\$~i",
               $db , $matches)) it gives 
    [0] => pgsql://sugumar:sugumar@192.168.8.20/sugumar
    [1] => pgsql
    [2] => sugumar
    [3] => sugumar
    [4] => 192.168.12.130
    [5] => 192.168.12.130
    [6] => sugumar
why the index 4 and 5 are same.

Comment: @ung Because you used two groups... You can use `(?:something here)` instead of `(something here)` for non-capturing groups.

Answer (score 1):

Look at

```
 print_r($matches);
```

after successful match. It should become clear.

From php docs here http://pl2.php.net/preg_match :

> If matches is provided, then
>   it is filled with the results of
>   search. $matches[0] will contain the
>   text that matched the full pattern,
>   $matches[1] will have the text that
>   matched the first captured
>   parenthesized subpattern, and so on.

Comment: preg_match("([a-zA-Z]*?)://([a-zA-Z]*?):([a-zA-Z]*?)@([a-zA-Z]*?)/([a-zA-Z]*?)$", $DB , $matches);

The above regular expression is my actual code.

print_r shows the following error
Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier ':'

Answer (score 1):

You have to pick a delimiter (typically, a character that is not used with the expression). The expression should start and end with the delimiter and you can optionally append flags after the closing deliminiter. E.g.:

```
preg_match("~(^([a-z]?)://([a-z]?):([a-z]?)@[a-z]?)/([a-z]*?)$)~i", $db , $matches);
```

You should consider to widen most character ranges: a username can contain numbers and a password can contain almost anything.

I suppose that the delimiters in the string (`:`, `//`, `@`...) won't necessarily be there if the corresponding parameters are optional.

Last but not least, as Kamil Szot already pointed out, parenthesized matches are loaded into the $matches variable.

Answer (score 1):

`php > preg_match("#([a-z]+)://([a-z]+):([a-z]+)@([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)$#", $var , $matches);`

`php > print_r($matches);`

`Array
(
    [0] => databasename://username:password@hostname/dbname
    [1] => databasename
    [2] => username
    [3] => password
    [4] => hostname
    [5] => dbname
)`